# Laravel can not send Response with token

Tags: laravel

I have this code

```
$token = (new Builder())->setIssuer('http://127.0.0.1:8000') // Configures the issuer (iss claim)
     ->setAudience('http://127.0.0.1:8000') // Configures the audience (aud claim)
     ->setId('4f1g23a12aa', true) // Configures the id (jti claim), replicating as a header item
     ->setIssuedAt(time()) // Configures the time that the token was issue (iat claim)
     ->setExpiration(time() + 3600) // Configures the expiration time of the token (exp claim)
     ->set('id', $user->id)
     ->set('name', $user->name)
     ->sign($signer, env('APP_KEY')) // creates a signature using enviroment variable APP_KEY as key
     ->getToken(); // Retrieves the generated token
echo $token . '<br>';
return new Response(['token' => $token], 200);
```

I am doing JWT token authetincation for users. The token itself is made just fine but somehow I cannot response with it.

```
SOMETOKENI6IjRmMWcyM2ExMmFhIJpc3MiOiJsadsadadodHRwOlwvXCImh0dHA6XC9cLzEyNy4wLjAuMTo4MDAwIiwianRpIjoiNGYxZzIzYTEyYWEiLCJTc0MjAsImV4cCI6MTUxOTIyMTAyMCwiaWQiOjEsIm5hbWUiOiJ1c2VyIn0.9413Cuf00CKdkDg
{"token":{}}
```

This is what my controller code prints out. 
It shows that when I echo the token is printed, but in response its empty. Why is that?

Comment: What displays when you `dd($user)`?

Comment: @Option Prints user correctly. I did `return new Response($token, 200);` it prints it, but I would like to get the property name too, so not sure why this works and my original solution does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Response::json(array('token'=>$token,'name'=>$name,'status'=>200));
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

I found fix that worked for me.

```
return new Response(['token' => "$token"], 200);
```

Somehow JWT token cant be added to array by just using `$token` variable.